# Directory-based music player for OS X

Tags: osx, music, media-player

I have directory with lot of subdirectories which all contain music.

I want a music player for OS X which automatically parses these subdirectories as playlists. I mean a filesystem-based music player, no DBs as in iTunes.

Comment: Tried Swinsian, VOX, MPlayerX, Cog, Kodi, Clementine, Nightingale.

Comment: Also tried Decibel, Audirvana Plus, Musique.